Proper File indexing display
I currently got a new task in my company to learn how recursive programming works, this is my current code to collect the data which I later will display:
public async Task TraverseAndStoreDirectory(string directoryPath, ODirectory parentDirectory = null)
{
    try
    {
        // Neues Verzeichnis erstellen
        var currentDirectory = new ODirectory
        {
            Name = Path.GetFileName(directoryPath),
            Size = CalculateDirectorySize(directoryPath),
            CreationDate = Directory.GetCreationTime(directoryPath),
            ParentDirectory = parentDirectory // Setze das Elternverzeichnis, wenn vorhanden
        };

        await MyServices.directoryService.CreateAsync(currentDirectory);


        // Dateien im aktuellen Verzeichnis verarbeiten und speichern
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath);
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
            var fileEntry = new OFile
            {
                Name = fileInfo.Name,
                Size = fileInfo.Length,
                FileType = fileInfo.Extension,
                CreationDate = fileInfo.CreationTime,
                ParentDirectory = currentDirectory
            };

            await MyServices.fileService.CreateAsync(fileEntry);
        }

        // Unterverzeichnisse im aktuellen Verzeichnis rekursiv verarbeiten
        string[] subDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(directoryPath);
        foreach (var subDirectory in subDirectories)
        {
            await TraverseAndStoreDirectory(subDirectory, currentDirectory); // Rekursiver Aufruf mit Elternverzeichnis
        }
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Zugriff verweigert: {e.Message}");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Fehler: {e.Message}");
    }
}

private long CalculateDirectorySize(string directoryPath)
{
    long size = 0;
    try
    {
        // Größe aller Dateien im Verzeichnis addieren
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath);
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
            size += fileInfo.Length;
        }

        // Größe aller Unterverzeichnisse rekursiv addieren
        string[] subDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(directoryPath);
        foreach (var subDirectory in subDirectories)
        {
            size += CalculateDirectorySize(subDirectory);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Fehler beim Berechnen der Verzeichnisgröße: {e.Message}");
    }
    return size;
}

Like you can see, we write this data into a database, later I read it from the db in my main class and then try to display it.
This is my current way to do it but it looks too complex for my liking:
public static void DisplayDirectoryStructure(ODirectory directory, int level = 0)
{
    // Ausgabe des aktuellen Verzeichnisses
    Console.WriteLine($"{new string(' ', level * 2)}{directory.Name} - {directory.Size} bytes");

    // Ausgabe der Dateien im aktuellen Verzeichnis
    foreach (var file in directory.Files)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{new string(' ', (level + 1) * 2)}{file.Name}{file.FileType} - {file.Size} bytes");
    }

    // Rekursiv die Unterverzeichnisse ausgeben
    foreach (var subDirectory in directory.Directorys)
    {
        DisplayDirectoryStructure(subDirectory, level + 1);
    }
}

I tried to do recursive file indexing, this is for now the simplest way I got it to work.
Now I try to display it in the console but it's too complex for my liking. Is there a simpler way to do it?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
